# UIButtonTypeSystem setBackgroundImage for UIControlStateHighlighted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ios7

In all my application i have UIButton with UIButtonTypeSystem. 
For ios7 I want to set buttons appearance programatically.
for normal state i need white background with blue border color
[image: normal state button]

for highlighted state i need grey background with blue border color
[image: highlighted state button]

(and for disabled state i need white background with grey border)

I created image for each state (containing background and border color)and I set them using the UIButton's method setBackgroungImage:forState:.
but when the button is in highlight state i get this button style 
[image: actual highlighted state button]

the only way to overcome this behavior that i found is to change all the application buttons type from UIButtonTypeSystem to UIButtonTypeCustom. meaning passing on all the application xib's

is there another way of doing so without changing all application buttons type

thanks
roi

Comment: are you looking forward to change the buttonType property to UIButtonTypeCustom programatically ?

Comment: I wish i could. I am looking for a way to make my buttons work in the way i described without changing the button types in the xibs

Comment: So you yourself is answering your question. Set the buttonType programatically and have a go...

Comment: How can i set the buttonType programatically?

Comment: I don't think that you can set the button type programatically. Once the button type is set you cannot change it.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can set you're button programatically like that:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[buuton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(180/255.0) blue:(200/255.0) alpha:1]];
[view addSubview:button];
```